# Adding ?isdtp=mn to Log A Call Button in Lightning

Tags: lightning, custom-button, url, sidebar, header

I am looking to add `?isdtp=mn` to the end of my Log A Call button's URL so I am able to pop the page with no sidebar or header.

When I add `isdtp` to the end of the URL link for the Log A Call button, I get no response in Lightning. I am curious if anyone knew the "why" behind this functionality.

So my question is why can't I add `isdtp=mn` to the end of my Log A Call URL in a Lightning console? I am able to do so in Salesforce Clasic.

`/00T/e?title=Call&who_id={!Lead.Id}&followup=1&tsk5=Call&retURL=/{!Lead.Id}?isdtp=mn`

Resources:

- https://www.ca-peterson.com/2011/12/08/the_magic_isdtp_param/
- http://theblogreaders.com/use-of-isdtp-parameter-in-salesforce/

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to screenshots you are not using Lightning console, rather using Classic Console.

In the console mode to open a window without header and side bar use `srcUp(pageUrl);`

> **The following piece of code handles both Console and Classic Mode to display the screen without sidebar and header.**

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/28.0/integration.js")} 

var pageUrl = '{!URLFOR($Action.Activity.LogCall)}'; 
var parameters = '?title=Call&who_id={!Lead.Id}'; 
var link = pageUrl + parameters; 
if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) 
{ 
    srcUp(pageUrl); 
} else { 
    window.open(pageUrl + '&isdtp=mn' ,'_blank'); 
}
```

Comment: So this actually worked without the srcUP(pageURL). I just needed to add in 'target: _blank' to the window.open - `window.open(pageUrl + '&isdtp=mn', 'Window Name', 'target: _blank');` The conditional wrapped around it is a great idea, this way it can pop differently for classic or lightning.

Comment: Refer my blog, to know different ways of navigation: http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/01/different-ways-of-navigation.html

Comment: basically `srcUp` and `srcSelf` specifically used for console, refer my blog you will get lot of examples